# Laundry air intake from the attic

Tags: attic, laundry

There is a washer-dryer, water heater and A/C furnace in my laundry room, all of them gas operated. There is an exhaust fan in the ceiling and an intake vent that connects directly to the attic so when the door of the laundry room is closed the air source of the laundry room is from the attic. Is this the way is supposed to be? Shouldn’t the laundry room get fresh air from outside? I have my attic cleaned and changed the insulation however the air in the attic is always heavy and dusty.

Answer (score 3):

It needs make-up air from somewhere.  Yes, ideally that air should come directly from outside, but depending on where you live (which you did not provide any information on location), pulling air from directly outside could lead to other problems in your laundry area if the air is very hot/humid, or extremely cold.

Depending on where you live and what your local code requirements are, you might be able to provide enough make-up air by putting a suitably-sized ventilation grille in your laundry door to let air in.  But if you have a very tight house from an air leak standpoint, that might not provide enough air coming in to compensate for what's being consumed by your heat sources in that room.  Also, if you put a grille in your door, that will allow a lot more laundry/HVAC noise to come out into whatever space is on the other side of the door, and if it's a common living area, that sound coming through the vent might be objectionable.  Finally, it was a lot cheaper for your house builder to just put a hole in the ceiling of the laundry room than it would have been to run an intake vent of sufficient size to the outside to provide make-up air.